# VS code "fileWatcher" constantly uses the CPU

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a problem not too long ago, fileWatcher uses the processor on a regular basis. I don't understand what happened.

"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node "c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork" --type=fileWatcher

[image]
[image]

The only thing that helps is deleting the folder:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Code Insiter

But it doesn't last long and the problem appears again.

Comment: I have the same problem on MacOS

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Add to `settings.json`:

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
"**/.git/objects/**": true,
"**/node_modules/**": true
}
```

and any other serverside folders that are likely to cause issues.